# VeraCrypt - Encryption of Host Protected Area on my Macbook Pro 13"

Tags: bootcamp, encryption

I have a MacBook Pro 13" Model : MGX82xx/A with Windows installed only (no Mac OS X on a different partition, no Boot Camp used (manual driver installation after windows installed.) and a copy of [VeraCrypt 1.0f1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/veracrypt/) installed.

Inside the VeraCrypt Volume Creation Wizard I have selected the options to **Encrypt the whole drive.**

I am being prompted with a yes/no Question - **Encryption of Host Protected Area**
Which states the following

*At the end of many drives, there is an area that is normally hidden from the operating system (such areas are usually referred to as Host Protected Areas). However, some programs can read and write data from/to such areas.
WARNING: Some computer manufacturers may use such areas to store tools and data for RAID, system recover, system setup, diagnostic, or other purposes. If such tools or data must be accessible before booting, the hidden area should NOT be encrypted (choose 'No' above).*

I would rather encrypt the Host Protected Area just to be sure, but do not want to damage my MacBook permanently if Apple reserve this space for whatever reason I do not know.

Can I encrypt this area?

Comment: Not knowing what you did to the original build and how you modified the SSD while installing Windows or seeing, at the very least, the output of `diskutil list /dev/disk0` in a Terminal... I'd guess it's talking about the **Recovery HD**.  Personally I'd not encrypt it and without testing I do not know whether it would have an adverse effect on it.  If I were doing it, I'd do testing in a virtual machine first.

Answer (score 1):

Download a decent but free partition tool for Windows like [MiniTool Partition Wizard Free Edition 9](http://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html) and check for a HFS+ volume at the end of the disk. The size is ~650 MB and the GUID type: 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECA.

If it doesn't exist anymore - after installing Windows - go ahead and encrypt the whole drive.

If it exists, try to boot to [Internet Recovery Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT4718) with <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to check if it works with your network setup. If you have been successful (you will see a little spinning globe and boot to a recovery screen), reboot to Windows and delete the Recovery HD-partition. Expand your Windows partition and encrypt the whole disk with VeraCrypt afterwards.
Using only Windows, the Mac Recovery HD partition on your disk device is almost useless.

Booted to Internet Recovery Mode you will always be able to reinstall a current Mac OS X given that you have a decent internet connection.